# Как прокинуть 1 файл из одного контейнера в другой?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

Есть два запущенных контейнера. Как прокинуть 1 файл из одного контейнера в другой?
Использовал volumes, как шару между контейнерами, но он поддерживает только папки целиком, но никак не файл. В докере вообще есть такая возможность?
Использую docker compose

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66473273/share-single-files-between-docker-containers